# Storyboard design issue when use MFTextField

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am using MFTextField for float label textfield, but i am facing one issue in designing.

[image: Error Image]

How i can solve this?

I have one solution to remove this error temporary, Not for permanent.

> Select MainView in ViewController.
>
> Press **Command + X**
>
> After that Press **Command + Z**

error is not display :)

When i close this project and reopen it display again :(

Comment: Update pod file on last with this lines and try.

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
  end
end